# How to label a Gmail message with IMAP_mailbox (imap-tools)?

Tags: python, gmail, imap, gmail-imap, imap-tools

We can fetch a Gmail mailbox using [Mailbox/IMAP_mailbox (`imap-tools`)](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/) as follows:

```
from imap_tools import MailBox as IMAP_mailbox

# Init
mailbox = IMAP_mailbox(HOST)
mailbox.login(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)

# Fetch
messages = mailbox.fetch(AND(seen=SEEN), bulk=BULK, mark_seen=MARK_SEEN, limit=LIMIT)
```

Then we can iterate through the messages as follows:

```
for message in messages:
    print(message)
```

To mark the message as seen we can do the following:

```
mailbox.seen(message.uid, True)
```

---

**However, instead of labelling it as seen, I would like assign a Gmail label to it. How can this be achieved? in this setup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use custom flag, example:

```
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    # FLAG unseen messages in current folder as \Seen, \Flagged and TAG1
    flags = (imap_tools.MailMessageFlags.SEEN, imap_tools.MailMessageFlags.FLAGGED, 'TAG1')
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.uids(AND(seen=False)), flags, True)
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/issues/123

Adding gmail label not implemented (not planned). Only search by them:

```
A(gmail_label='hello')
```

Comment: Seems to be added now? https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/releases/tag/v0.42.0

Comment: Is this possible now?